# foreach not working for some reason

Tags: php, foreach

I've this part of my script which shows last offers my website is given but for some reason it shows the same offer 3 times as image showing.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMAu2.png)

This is the code coming with the script

```
<?php foreach($specialoffers as $offer) if ($tmp++ < 3) { ?>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php if($specialoffers[0]->price > 0){ ?> <span class="wow bounce ttu"><?php echo trans('0536');?> <b><?php echo trans('0388');?></b> <small><?php echo $specialoffers[0]->currCode;?></small> <?php echo $specialoffers[0]->currSymbol; ?><?php echo $specialoffers[0]->price;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="imgLodBg">
        <div class="load"></div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>offers">
        <img data-wow-duration="0.2s" data-wow-delay="1s" class="wow fadeIn" src="<?php echo $specialoffers[0]->thumbnail;?>">
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="offh3"><strong class="ttu"><?php echo character_limiter($specialoffers[0]->title,30);?></strong></h3>
        <p class="offp">
            <?php echo character_limiter($specialoffers[0]->desc,240);?>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>offers" >
            Read More
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and when I tried the below changes the page crashed and I got this error

> [12-Aug-2018 13:48:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type
>   stdClass as array in
>   /home/bannabooking/public_html/beta/themes/default/views/home/index.php
>   on line 152

Changed Code:

```
<?php foreach($specialoffers as $offer) if ($tmp++ < 3) { ?>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php if($offer[0]->price > 0){ ?> <span class="wow bounce ttu"><?php echo trans('0536');?> <b><?php echo trans('0388');?></b> <small><?php echo $offer[0]->currCode;?></small> <?php echo $offer[0]->currSymbol; ?><?php echo $offer[0]->price;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="imgLodBg">
        <div class="load"></div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>offers">
        <img data-wow-duration="0.2s" data-wow-delay="1s" class="wow fadeIn" src="<?php echo $offer[0]->thumbnail;?>">
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="offh3"><strong class="ttu"><?php echo character_limiter($offer[0]->title,30);?></strong></h3>
        <p class="offp">
            <?php echo character_limiter($offer[0]->desc,240);?>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>offers" >
            Read More
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is `$specialoffers` a multidimensional array?

Comment: Which line is #152?

Comment: MCEmperor yes but already fixed as Ivan Velichko Reply, Terminus it's line 4 here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `foreach () {}` you already have individual `$offers` objects. So, instead of accessing them via `$offer[0]->price`, you need directly access each `$offer->price`, `$offer->desc`, etc.

In general, the `foreach () {}` approach looks like this:

```
$offers = [new Offer('a'), new Offer('b')];
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    // $offer here sequentially corresponds 
    // to each element of the $offers array
    echo $offer->price;
}
```

Another way to accomplish iteration over `$offers` array may look like this:

```
$offers = [new Offer('a'), new Offer('b')];
for ($i = 0; $i < array_length($offers); $i++) {
    echo $offers[$i]->price;
}
```

So, you just need to stick with one of these approaches. And usually `foreach` looks more accurate.

Comment: Thanks you saved me :D